# What happens if don't consume enough fat?

Tags: diet, nutrition, bodybuilding

My aim is to build body. I've been working out in gym for past 2-3 weeks now. I train my full body hard thrice a week and 2 hours per workout day. Considering myself "very active" [Interactive DRI for health professionals](http://fnic.nal.usda.gov/fnic/interactiveDRI/) recommends:

```
Daily Caloric Needs: 3199 kcal/day
Carbohydrate    360 - 520 grams
Protein 48 grams
Fat 71 - 124 grams
```

I've no problem meeting my Carbohydrate requirement. I'm trying my best to meet protien requirement but some how I'm missing out on meeting Fat. I've quite a bit of Fat in my body so I'm not consuming more than 30-40 grams of fat.

What happens if I don't consume enough fat? Should I increase my Fat intake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

40 grams of fat would be 360 calories, which is a little more than 10% of your 3200 calories. That's not a bad range to be in, although it might be a little bit on the low side.

Fat serves a lot of different purposes in the body, including insulation, shock absorption and energy storage. The most important thing about fat, however, is that the vitamins A, D, E and K are what are called fat soluble.

This means that the only way those vitamins can be transported into the body is via fat transport, so if you have too little fat then you run the risk of developing vitamin deficiencies.

Comment: I'm taking vitamin supplements everyday, as that is the only way to fulfill my vitamin requirements. So you mean to say even my supplements would be wasted? I take these supplements with breakfast&dinner which definitely involve some fat in it. Is that ok?

Comment: 1. is there something like if I don't take enough fat, my body uses fat stored in my body? 2. Thing is even though I'm lean I've FUPA and I'm aiming at 6 pack so increasing lean muscle mass and decreasing fat is my goal.

Comment: @claws - You know that FUPA is a made up derogatory term, right? And no, if you need fat in your diet to transport the vitamins. Your body won't "pull fat" into the intestine to transport them. And I hate to tell you, but if the "only way" to get all your vitamins in a day is by supplements, your diet sucks.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that its a derogatory term, I thought it was a medical term.

Comment: My diet every day includes 300-400g rice, 250g cooked chicken breast, 250ml milk, 3-4 slices of bread with peanut butter, 1 egg mostly but sometimes 2 eggs, curry made of either pulses or vegetable once a day. And my supplements include- miltivitamin (once), calcium 500mg (twice). What changes must I make to make my diet "not suck"

Comment: More fruits and vegetables. You should be able to get all nutrients from a balanced diet.

Comment: vegetables & fruits are costlier than my supplements. I'm also looking at my budget. But sure, I'll try to incorporate as per your suggestion.